# Rademacher complexity of logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, probability

Consider logistic regression. We have the logistic loss function,
$\phi: R\rightarrow [0,1], \phi(u)=\log(1+\exp(-u))$, which is Lipschitz, and we have the linear function class $F=\{f_w:R^d \rightarrow R, f_w(x)=w^Tx, \forall x\in R^d\}$.
Given a training set, $S=\{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N,y_N)\}$, we do empirical risk minimization to estimate the parameter $\hat{w}$:
$\hat{f}_{\hat{w}} = argmin_{f_w} \sum_{n=1}^N\phi(y_nf_w(x_n))$.

I am interested in a bound on the generalisation error of of $\hat{f}_{\hat{w}}$. Can this be obtained using Rademacher complexities without introducing restrictions of boundedness on the parameter space and on the input space? Alternatively, I would also be interested in a VC bound (since no such boundedness assumptions would be needed), but as far as I understand, for that I would need to use hard-thresholded values of the values of $f$ and work with the 0/1 loss (which is different from what the ERM algorithm is optimising).

The Rademacher approach that I was able to find unfortunately makes the following modification to the problem: It assumes that $\forall f\in F, \|f\|_\infty < B$ for some $0<B<\infty$. The function class is hence replaced with another one:
 $F_{trunc}=\{f_w:S^{d-1} \rightarrow [-B,B], f_w(x)=w^Tx, \forall x\in S^{d-1}; \|w\|<B \}$. I understand this is related to regularisation.

My problem is that this modification doesn't suit the problem that I am working on, and I wonder if there is any way to avoid it. I can see that it would be very convenient for the Rademacher complexity based bounding technique, since then by the Ledoux-Talagrand contraction inequality we get $\hat{R}_N(\phi\circ F_{trunc})\le L_{\phi}\hat{R}_N(F_{trunc})$ (where $\hat{R}_N(.)$ denotes the empirical Rademacher complexity, $N$ is the number of training points, and $L_{\phi}$ is the Lipschitz constant of $\phi$), and $\hat{R}_N(F_{trunc})$ can be estimated neatly as $\hat{R}_N(F_{trunc})\le B/\sqrt{N}$. However, I am interested in $\hat{R}_N(\phi\circ F)$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Rademacher definition is general for any function: http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~khashab2/learn/rademacher.pdf

Comment: When we can find the VC-dimension of logistic regression directly why do we need to bound it using Rademacher sum?

Comment: Or maybe I am still not getting what you are saying...

Comment: If we could find a good VC bound then we wouldn't need a Rademacher bound.

Comment: Rademacher sum is one way to bound VC-dimension based risk. But for logistic regression why not finding the generalization bound directly? Have you seen the derivations to find the generalization bound in this? http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-discriminativegenerative.pdf

Comment: But I notice they work with the 0/1 loss rather than the logistic loss, which is different from what the ERM algorithm is doing. With the 0/1 loss and truncating the sigmoid values at 0.5 of course the standard VC bound applies.

Comment: ok, so what is wrong with " they work with the 0/1 loss" which is truncation of the logistic loss?

Comment: The algorithm minimises a different loss. And I'd also like an approach that would work in other similar settings - the logistic regression problem is mostly just for concreteness. I was wondering if there is some well-known approach that I'm missing.

Comment: @Daniel It seems that you have a sense of how to write an answer of this question. Perhaps you could collect your comments into an answer?

Comment: @axk there seems to be some problem with what you said, assuming $\|f\|_{\infty}< B$ for all $f$ is a lot more restrictive than assuming $\|w\|\le B$, we are dealing with linear functions hence we never have $\|f\|_{\infty}< B$ except if we suppose that the feature space is bounded. On the other hand, it seems natural to suppose $\|w\|\le B$ or even $\|w\|=1$ because what we are interested in is only the sign of f and we don't really care about its scale.